# App Service managed identity connection to Azure SQL database login fails for token-identified principal

Tags: authentication, azure-sql-database, blazor-server-side, azure-managed-identity

App Service dev, staging and prod deployment slots and SQL DB all have system assigned managed identities.
Contributor roles have been assigned to managed identities at the subscription level.

SQL Server Contained users have been created and roles assigned for the App Service dev, staging and production slots:
[SQL Server Contained Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkXIx.png)

appsettings.json connectionStrings:
[connectionStrings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32CQc.png)

AD DB Admin User created and added to SQLServer as a contained user.

Permissions added to AppService managed identity for dB1 and dB2 to [SQL Server AppService Managed Identity Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4UuQ.png)

msi-validator returns success for token based connection from the web app to two different databases on the same sql server instance.
[msi-validator success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBnK1.png)

Local and Azure deployment slot both return: [SQLException Login failed for token-identified principal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQVn7.png)

Walked through https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53928.azure-ad-managed-identity-connecting-azure-web-app-and-slots-with-azure-sql-db-without-credentials.aspx and many other tutorials.

Still missing something...

Attempts to run the application using the managed identity connection string is consistently failing with the token-provider principal login failure error.

Confirmation of settings:
[Confirmation of Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry6ZF.png)

Comment: Looks like you did everything that I also tried. In my case I have a production slot and a beta slot. On both I did the same configuration and the beta slot works, but my production (main slot) does not. I even cloned the production slot to a deployment slot and then it did work.

In my case I am using net6 with EF Core 6 so I added nuget Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and changed the connectionstring.  This works in de beta slot but not in de production slot.

Keeping an eye on this thread :-)

Comment: I started with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity and continued to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-sql-database for .Net and EF Core 6 This ends up with most the same you have I'm stumped as well why this does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure the Azure Active Directory user is created on the Azure SQL Database. Please make you create the user in the Azure SQL Database following the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell&view=azuresql#create-contained-database-users-in-your-database-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities).

To create an Azure AD-based contained database user, connect to the database with an Azure AD identity, as a user with at least the ALTER ANY USER permission. Then use the following Transact-SQL syntax:

```
  CREATE USER <Azure_AD_principal_name> FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
  CREATE USER [bob@contoso.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
  CREATE USER [alice@fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

Make sure you are connect to the Azure SQL database and not to the master database on the Azure SQL logical server.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have confirmed that the AD DB admin and the app service system assigned managed identity have both been created as contained users (FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER) on the databases and that they have been added to the db_datareader, db_datawriter and db_ddladmin roles.

Comment: Hi Alberto, You were right! I missed the managed identity for the second database. This resolved the Azure deployment slot error.

Comment: Also, by changing the logged in user in Visual Studio to use the AD DB Admin account, I am able to access the database when I run the application locally. Thank you very much.

Comment: @OK1 So you forgot to do the CREATE USER statements for DB2 ? Well I'm on my own again.

Comment: @JohanBennink Missing the dev slot managed identity user on DB2 caused the error in the dev slot and not using the AD DB Admin in Visual Studio caused the same error when running locally. Other than these, you can see all of the relevant configuration (I think) in my question. I had to recreate some entities and rename the resource group on the portal because I was using the same name as the app service. This is fine in the portal but SQL Server doesn't allow you to create an External Provider user unless the name is unique. I hope that you resolve this in less time than it took me!

Comment: @OK1 Sorry for my late reply. I answered late last night. I am glad you found the missing managed identity.

Comment: P.S. In my case it was user error. Those two losts i mentioned were not the same. In fact the beat one disabled HangFire and exactly there the problem arose. I had to supply a connection instead of the connectionstring to get it to process Managed Identity propertply as described in this issue https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1946

Comment: @JohanBennink Please make this an answer and describe in detail, it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are facing an error stating login fails for token-identified principal when trying to connect your Azure ap service managed identity with your Azure SQL Database.
Could you please try the below in order to mitigate the issue.

1. Make sure System managed Identity status is showing on your app.
2. on your app service Verify that your connection string under application settings is set to "Server=tcp:.database.windows.net,1433;Database=;"
3. Allow Azure services and resources to access this server” should be set as Yes in Firewalls and virtual networks settings in your Azure SQL DB, in case it was not set earlier during Azure SQL setup.

Please do let me know if that help mitigate the issue. If not, we will keep working on the same to get you unblock.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have edited my post to show confirmations of the settings. The only thing I changed was to add port 1433 to the connection string. This does not resolve the issue. Any further suggestions will be welcome.